# Databricks / Spark equivalent to lookup (done via CROSS APPLY in SQL)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

My users have a small sparse configuration of "scaling factors" they wish to apply to a table of fixed size (50,000 rows).

This is how it's currently configured and turned into a small dataframe:

```py
rank_lbounds  = [   0, 101, 175,  250, 500, 50000]
scale_factors = [0.64, 0.6, 0.8, 0.99, 1.0,   1.0]

from pyspark.sql import Row
ScalingFactor = Row("rank_min", "scale_factor")
df_scaling_factors = spark.createDataFrame(
  [ScalingFactor(rank, scale) for (rank, scale) in zip(rank_lbounds, scale_factors)])
```

The idea is that a result set (50,000 rows) will get sorted from largest to smallest, and then the first 100 values will get scaled down by a factor of 0.64, the next 75 by 0.6, etc...

In SQL, the "go-to" approach to do this kind of thing efficiently is apparently `CROSS APPLY`. This is the solution they have:

```sql
SELECT SomeKey, SomeValue, SomeValue_Rank, ScaleFactor,
       SomeValue_Scaled = (SomeValue * ScaleFactor)
FROM (
    SELECT SomeKey, SomeValue, SomeValue_Rank,
        T_FactorLookup.rank_min AS NextLowestRankLookup,
        T_FactorLookup.Rank_ScaleFactor AS ScaleFactor
    FROM (
        SELECT SomeKey, SomeValue,
               SomeValue_Rank = row_number() over(order by SomeValue desc, SomeKey)
        FROM dbo.TableOfValuesToScale
    ) AS T_Ranked
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT TOP 1 rank_min, Rank_ScaleFactor
        FROM Extortion_VoR_Scalefactors AS Factors
        WHERE Factors.rank_min <= SomeValue_Rank
        ORDER BY Factors.rank_min DESC
    ) T_FactorLookup
) T_WithScaleFactors
```

In attempting to port this to databricks, I'm not sure what the best way to do this same kind of lookup is. I know the lookup table will always be teeny tiny (sparse), so procedurally, I would have no qualms about implementing this as a double nested for loop, or a cartesian join with filter, but I'd like to use best practices lest the example be used on larger data sets.

Solutions I've considered:

- Using the source SQL as-is (but `CROSS APPLY` is not supported in sparksql)
- CROSS JOIN with filter (slow cartesian product, not recommended)
- "exploding" the small `df_scaling_factors` table into a 50,000 row table manually, and doing a simple join on the `row_number() over...` = `rank_min`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for joining on row number. Perhaps you could add one more column to the scaling factor table to facilitate joining.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, Window, functions as F

rank_lbounds  = [   0, 101, 175,  250, 500]
rank_ubounds  = [ 100, 174, 249,  499, 50000]
scale_factors = [0.64, 0.6, 0.8, 0.99, 1.0]

ScalingFactor = Row("rank_min", "rank_max", "scale_factor")
df_scaling_factors = spark.createDataFrame(
  [ScalingFactor(rankl, ranku, scale)
   for (rankl, ranku, scale) in zip(rank_lbounds, rank_ubounds, scale_factors)])

df2 = df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('value')))

joined = df2.join(
    df_scaling_factors,
    (df2.rn >= df_scaling_factors.rank_min) & (df2.rn <= df_scaling_factors.rank_max)
)
joined2 = joined.withColumn('scaled_values', F.col('scale_factors') * F.col('value'))
```

Comment: I like it. It's fairly straightforward. Only change I made was to derive `rank_ubounds  = [ x-1 for x in rank_lbounds[1:] ] + [50000]` to avoid the extra config data.

Comment: Also used `Window.orderBy(F.col('value').desc())` to capture the nuance of descending sort order.